# NancyFX: Can I force my unit-test browser to be authenticated by default?

Tags: unit-testing, nancy

Here is a unit test that shows me authenticating my Nancy browser (other code has been snipped out). I was wondering if there was a smarter, DRYer way to do this?

```
[Fact]
public void Login__Should_redirect_from_login_to_requested_page_if_credentials_are_correct()
{
    var browser = Fake.Browser();
    var response = browser.Post("/login", with =>
                                         {
                                           with.HttpRequest();
                                           with.FormValue("UserName", userName);
                                           with.FormValue("Password", password);
                                          });
    response.ShouldHaveRedirectedTo("/");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a method that delivers back a Browser instance:`Fake.Browser()` so why not just rewrite this to provide an authenticated version if required. Something like this perhaps:

```
public static Browser Browser(string username = null, string password = null)
{
    var browser = new Browser(new UnitTestBootstrapper());
    if (username.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty()) return browser;
    return browser.Post("/login", with =>
                                        {
                                            with.HttpRequest();
                                            with.FormValue("Username", username);
                                            with.FormValue("Password", password);
                                        }).Then;
}
```

Comment: Ah - good idea. I was confused by the need to have `.Then` but of course ... its passing back the browser instance from the fluid interface. Nice :-)